# Mosquitto 3.1.1 no Ubunto 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, mqtt

Quando instalo o mosquitto pelo apt-get ele faz a instalação da versão 3.1, entretando essa versão não suporta o parametro -F no mosquitto_sub, presente somente na versão 3.1.1

Como instalar a ultima versao do mosquitto por apt-get?

Comment: Já tentou adicionar o repositório oficial e baixá-lo por ele https://mosquitto.org/blog/2013/01/mosquitto-debian-repository/ ?